# Entity Framework 7 with ASP.NET 4.6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

The question is quite simple: Is it possible to use `Entity Framework 7` (beta4) with `ASP.NET 4.6` (Web Api in my case)?

For the moment I cannot make it work, the following exception is always raised:

> An exception of type `System.InvalidCastException` occured in
>   Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.Interfaces.dll but was not
>   handled in user code.
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   Microsoft.Framework.Logging.LoggerFactory to type
>   Microsoft.Framework.Logging.ILoggerFactory.

This error is quite strange since I do not use any logging functionnality of EF 7. It has maybe something with registration to do? I read that with ASP.NET 5, you have to register EF like this: `services.AddEntityFramework()`, which I'm currently not doing since I'm using Version 4.6...

Comment: What does your project.json look like?

Comment: Like I wrote, I use ASP.NET 4.6, thus no `project.json`...

Comment: What does your `packages.config` and `<runtime>` section of your `Web.config` look like?

Comment: I managed to make it work with the latest beta6-13679 nightly build. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a possibly likely a bug in EF 7. The issue is being tracked here [aspnet/EntityFramework#2606](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2606).

**Update**

As a workaround, try [using the nightly builds](http://peternewhook.com/2015/04/getting-started-with-asp-net-5-nightly-builds-on-windows/) and make sure that you have the latest versions of both EF 7, Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection, and Microsoft.Framework.Logging.

Comment: How to test Entity Framework 7 then? Is there a workaround? I tried to downgrade to beta 3, but obviously that's not possible...

Comment: Updated. Try using a newer build of EF and its dependencies.

Comment: Ok, then I will try with the latest beta6-13679. I'm currently using the beta4 (the latest available version via the official nuget)

Comment: Welcome to the world of nightly builds. Expect many more bugs. Feel free to contribute at https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues

Comment: Humm it does not work, I updated my Nuget repository with the url you suggested, but when I try to install the beta6-13679, I see the following message in the VS Output Console: "Attempting to resolve dependencies for package (...)" and then it hangs up... Do you know when the next official beta (5) will be released?

Comment: Mmhmmm ok, I tried on another computer with Visual Studio 2013 and it worked... So obviously something is not working with the beta6 package and Visual Studio 2015 RC...

Comment: I finally managed to make it work, but it was really a pain... At the end, I did have a new bug with Remotion.Linq. It seems that the version 2.00-beta-002 is not working with ef beta7... downgrading this dll to version 2.00-alpha-004 did the trick... ouch!